# jQuery: scrolling to id #span[title] when clicking on span[title]

Tags: jquery

I already have a solution to the problem specified in the title. Unfortunately it only works in Chrome and i can't figure out why. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$("span[title]").click(function() {
$('body', 'html').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + $(this).attr('title')).offset().top - 60}, "slow");
return false;
});

});
```

[Demo](http://alexander-pastor.de/startseite.html): Click on the toolbar (gear icon at the bottom). Then click on "Nach oben" or "Nach unten".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/94addpz6/1/).

Click on any of the text at the top, and it will place that subsection of the page at the top of the window.

Watch the console and you can see what it's doing.

JS

```
$("div").on('click', function() {
   var divclass = $(this).attr('class');
     console.log('divclass = ' + divclass);
   var x = $('#' + divclass).offset().top;
     console.log(x);
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: x}, 500);
   return false;
});
```

And here is the code to make a div/span/etc specific for the click - just add a name='link' to the element.

```
$("div[name='link']").on('click', function() {
   var divclass = $(this).attr('class');
     console.log('divclass = ' + divclass);
   var x = $('#' + divclass).offset().top;
     console.log(x);
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: x}, 500);
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but this does not solve my problem. I need some code that scrolls to ANY id #x when clicking on a span with the title x. So if i got spans with the titles x,y and z and so forth, clicking on each of them should scroll to the respective id's offset.

Comment: Ok, so how many spans do want to click on (your page only has two that you click on)? How many destinations do you want to go to (your page goes to the top or bottom)?

Comment: I wanted to use the code on navigation sections such as in the left column of the following link: http://alexander-pastor.de/anorganische-chemie.html

Comment: This works perfectly. I changed the code a little (replaced divclass with spantitle) to suit the the original question. Thank you very much, sir! By the way, do you have any idea why the code i posted does not work in some browsers?

Comment: A great weakness of mine is differences between browsers - a wild guess is the .animate - but you could check it with the debug on the browser and see what error you get.